# How to override default odoo 8 website header section

Tags: odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to override default header section of odoo 8 website with my own design but am getting errors when i use xpath expression and do a replace. See code below :

header.xml code

```
   <template id="layout_replace_menu_header" customize_show="True" inherit_id="website.layout" name="custom_header_replace">
      <xpath expr="//div[@class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top']" position="replace">
          <header>
              <div class="header">
                      <div class="container">
                        <a class="site-logo" href="#"><img src="/themeotb2/static/otbassets/img/logo.png" alt="image" /></a>

                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mobi-toggler"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>

                        <!-- BEGIN NAVIGATION -->
                        <div class="header-navigation pull-right font-transform-inherit">
                          <ul>               
                                <t t-foreach="website.menu_id.child_id" t-as="submenu">
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                         <t t-call="website.submenu"/>
                                    </li> 

                                </t>
                            <!-- BEGIN TOP SEARCH -->
                            <li class="menu-search">
                              <span class="sep"></span>
                              <i class="fa fa-search search-btn"></i>
                              <div class="search-box">
                                <form action="#">
                                  <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" />
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                </form>
                              </div> 
                            </li>
                            <!-- END TOP SEARCH -->
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END NAVIGATION -->
                      </div>
                    </div>    
          </header>

        </xpath>
    </template>
```

When i use "inside" instead of replace the code will execute but when i do replace odoo complains with errors:

```
  File "/opt/openerp/ttfa/projectdatabase/src/openerp/models.py", line 1270, in _validate_fields
raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

 Error details:
  Element '<xpath expr="//header//a[@class='navbar-brand']">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
 View `Show Logo`
```

How can i solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Either You have to override template "layout_logo_show" or disable "Show Logo" from website Customize setting.

Thank You!